# Kapt annotation processing - how to show full stacktrace

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, kapt

I am working on a android project using Kotlin, Databinding and Room.
Sometimes the build fails with a error message, containing no information about what exactly went wrong, except that it has something to do with the annotation processor (which can have many causes...).

shortened Example:

> org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains

[more stack trace lines]

> Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.util.KaptBaseError: Error while annotation processing

[even more stack trace lines]

> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt(Kapt.kt:45)
>     ... 32 more

Finding the cause, then means time consuming backtracking of my steps (and maybe using `git stash`) and guessing, when one the 32 hidden lines at the end seems likely to contain some useful information about what actually went wrong.

So the question is: **how to show the full stack trace?**

I tried setting the `-Xmaxerrs 500` in my `build.gradle` as shown here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html#java-compiler-options as well as various variants of this, I found on SE (sorry, don't remember which exactly).
None made any difference. Maybe i put the block in the wrong part? (tried module level, android -> defaultConfig -> kapt)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60324017/kapt-annotation-processing-how-to-show-full-stacktrace

Answer (score 23):

Add `kapt.verbose=true` to your project's `gradle.properties` file.

Comment: unfortunately this does not change anything :(

Comment: I did see more output after doing this.

Comment: It works for me.
And I find dagger compile error after enable it

Comment: This worked for me after hours of scratching my head. Found a silly issue in the output.

Comment: It worked for me as well. With the verbose log I was able to identify the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the issue was apparently with the 'suspend' keyword added to my Dao function. I may be missing dependency or there may be some dependency issue.

For example I changed the following:

```
    @Query("select * from election_table")
**suspend** fun getAllElections():LiveData<List<Election>>
```

to

```
    @Query("select * from election_table")
fun getAllElections():LiveData<List<Election>>
```

Room version: = "2.2.5"

Update: Yep - the issue is ensure you have the following dependencies:

```
 //Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$version_room"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$version_room"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$version_room"
```

I was missing the last one. Added suspend keyword again, and now compiles like a charm!